# Символ \n не преобразуется в Enter на питоне

Tags: python-3.x, строки, sqlite, вконтакте

В файле есть одна строка. Но даже она отправляется пользователю вк-бота как

```
\n Вот расписание: 5а 6 Test \n
```

С двумя строками, разделёнными Enter-ом, происходит точно такое же:

```
\ntest_first_line \n test_second_line \n
```

К слову, я читаю из файла нужный мне участок, переношу его в БД, потом изымаю его оттуда, преобразую обратно в строку и отправляю. И \n перестаёт восприниматься компьютером. Если же я просто напишу

```
text="\ntest_first_line \n test_second_line \n"
```

Всё отработает как надо, будет перенос строки. Пишу на питоне, использую sqlite3, в чём проблема не понимаю. Помогите.

Comment: Вы бы показали свои преобразования - сейчас ничего не понятно

Comment: cursor.execute("SELECT raspisanie FROM raspisanie WHERE dated = ? AND grade=? AND userid=?", params)
            texts = cursor.fetchall()
            texts=str(texts)

Comment: raspisanie = f[f.find(num+let+" "+date)+4:f.find(num+let+" "+date+".")]
                upload_massive_of_raspisanie(raspisanie,grade,date,"Example")

Comment: Это вывод из БД и ввод в неё.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогло это:

```
text=text.replace(r"\n",'\n')
```

Comment: А если там не только `\n` ?

Comment: У меня была проблема только в этом. Но за расширенный вариант спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что в ваших строках каким-то чудесным образом(вы ведь не раскроете нам этот секрет, верно?) появились сырые слеши вместо экранирования.
Их можно декодировать заново:

```
text = r'Line 1\nLine 2'
fixed_text = bytes(text, 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
print(text)
print(fixed_text)
```

Но лучше найти в своём коде участок, который портит ваши строки)

Comment: Да там при занесении в БД строки портились.

Comment: Это не всегда надо использовать! Я протестировал на странных символах, у меня всё рухнуло. Кто хочет от всего сразу избавиться - используйте, но вариант точечного применения в некоторых случаях лучше